# TypeError: object is not callable when putting ICS in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I am currently learning how to do differential equations on Python using `SymPy`.

```
def problem():

    alpha, beta, t = symbols('alpha beta t', real=True)
    s = Function('s')(t)

    expr = Eq(s.diff(t), alpha*s**2 + beta*s)

    print(expr)
    print(sympy.dsolve(expr, simplify=True, ics={s(0): 1000}))
```

It always gives me `TypeError: object 's' is not callable` when putting the initial condition (it works and give me general solution with C1 when I remove ics)

Anyone can help with this?

Comment: It's saying that `s(0)` is wrong; `s` is not a Python function.  It's a `sympy.Function`, but that's not the same thing.  You'll need read the relevant `sympy` docs more.

Comment: Define `s = Function('s')` and every subsequent use of `s` in your code should be replaced with `s(t)` except the ics argument.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `s.subs(t, 0): 1000`.